# Run taskmgr.exe without administrator rights?

Tags: c#, process

I NEED to run Task Manager with the very specific code that I have, but it is appearing with an access denied error.

I have attempted to run in administrator mode before.

`FileStream fs = new FileStream(System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.SystemDirectory, "taskmgr.exe"), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None);`

The expected result I want is that Task Manager opens using the code above, without administrator rights! (Is there anyway around this?)

Comment: That opens a file for reading and writing, it doesn't actually run the executable. To actually start it you'd probably need to use `Process.Start` .

Comment: Yes use the System.Diagnostice.Process class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(); //a processstartinfo object
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false; //just hides the window if set to true
startInfo.UseShellExecute = true; //use shell (current programs privillage)
startInfo.FileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.SystemDirectory, "taskmgr.exe"); //The file path and file name
startInfo.Arguments = ""; //Add your arguments here

Process.Start(startInfo);
```

**Resources:**

- [ProcessStartInfo - MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Purrfect! Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

This is a start process function I have

```cs
using System.Diagnostics;

private static void StartProcess(string exeName, string parameter)
{
    using (Process process = new Process())
    {
        process.StartInfo.FileName = exeName; 
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = parameter;
        process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        process.Start();
    }
}
```

Then call it like

```cs
StartProcess("exename.exe", fileParameter);
```

[Process Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process?view=netframework-4.8)